# How to prevent resource leaks while using Open/Save file dialog in c#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, resource-leak

we are using save/opn file dialog in our desktop application(C#).
When we open the dialog for the first time, handles are increased by 100. After closing the dialog the handles are not getting reduced. From the next time onwards handles are increasing by 10 or so and getting reduced by 2 to 4.

We tried decreasing the handles by calling dispose and making it null.
And also tried with using block.
But none of them solved the issue.

Could you please tell me any work around for this? Or can we use any custom control or so

Please advice on this

Thanks in advance

code:
The code is

```
SaveFileDialog objSaveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
try
{

    objSaveDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    objSaveDialog.Title = "Save to Text File";
    //objSaveDialog.ShowDialog();
    DialogResult dlgResult = objSaveDialog.ShowDialog();
    objSaveDialog.Dispose();
    if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string strSaveFilePath = objSaveDialog.FileName;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSaveFilePath))
        {
            TextWriter myTxtWriter = new StreamWriter(strSaveFilePath, false);
            for (int index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
            {
                myTxtWriter.WriteLine("sample text.....................................");
            }

            myTxtWriter.Flush();
            myTxtWriter.Close();
            myTxtWriter.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if (objSaveDialog != null)
    {
        objSaveDialog = null;
        //((IDisposable)objSaveDialog).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very unlikely that there really is a leak. Show some minimal code that purports to demonstrate it. Don't make us guess what your code is.

Comment: Looking at the Task Manager is not a sufficient way of detecting a memory or resource leak... Use a profiler instead

Comment: I'd be very surprised if, after all these years, the common dialog box had a memory leak that nobody had spotted until now..

Comment: If you perform a full GC (e.g. `GC.Collect();                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`) do the handles get reclaimed then? It's possible that something is holding onto handles until a finalizer is called.

Comment: Hi chibacity, I tried calling GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); . But still the handles remain same. Could you please advise

Comment: I don't think your code is correct, why dispose the objSaveDialog then assign strSaveFilePath = objSaveDialog.FileName.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of code gets loaded into your process when you open a shell dialog.  All of the shell extension handlers installed on your machine.  Code you didn't write.  You can see them getting loaded in the Output window when you tick the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" option in the Project + Properties, Debug tab.

Having these shell extension handlers misbehave and leak resources is certainly not uncommon.  You can use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to disable them.  Start with the ones not written by Microsoft.